# JavaScript use object content

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to separate some values that come from an AJAX request.
They look like this:

```
Object { name: "fsdfsd", details: "sdfsdf", password: "sdfsdgds" }
```

And I'd basically need them separated each value in its variable. How can I do that?
I've searched around but can't find a good answer. I'm used to PHP syntax like `$this->output` and I just moved to using JS more than once in a month so I'm still trying to accomodate :)
Thank you!

Comment: Do you get that string on the server side or on the client side? So _where_ do you want to "extract" those values?

Comment: @arkascha I get them in the view through an AJAX request that calls a controller (working in CodeIgniter). This is the content I need but now I have to populate a few inputs, each with its value

Comment: That did not answer my question, sorry.

Comment: I'm getting that from server side and I need to "print" it on client side. I get it as JSON Object and now I have to separate the values.

Comment: So the answer is: on the client side. OK, then the answers below should be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var res = { name: "fsdfsd", details: "sdfsdf", password: "sdfsdgds" };
var name = res.name;
var details = res.details;
var password = res.password;
```

But I strongly recommend you to use res as object. You could use less number of variables and have less potential problems. AND DON'T SEND PASSWORD AS A PLAIN TEXT! Someone can listen your traffic and dump all your users passwords.

Comment: I know about security problems with sending passwords, still, I'm working on a small internal platform where employees store simple passwords like for Windows, for Skype etc. so nothing to worry about. Thanks for the heads up though!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a ES6 version if you want

It uses [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). It will only work in the latest browsers

```js
var res = { name: "fsdfsd", details: "sdfsdf", password: "sdfsdgds" }

var {name, details, password} = res

console.log(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var objectName = { name: "fsdfsd", details: "sdfsdf", password: "sdfsdgds" }
var name = objectName.name;
var details = objectName.details;
var password = objectName.password;
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to separate them.
by the look of it the ajax request is returning a json object.
store it a variable.
ex:

```
var returnObj = getServicerequest(input); // ajax request that you call is handled in this function.
```

now you can access the value pairs like:

```
alert(returnObj.name);
alert(returnObj.datails);
```

however returning username and passwords via ajax calls are not a good security practise.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
var res = {
  name: "fsdfsd",
  details: "sdfsdf",
  password: "sdfsdgds"
}
var Obj = res.name + " " + res.details + " " + res.password
console.log(Obj)
```

Comment: OP wants to destruct the object to separate variables. So this is not the answer he is looking for

Answer (score 0):

You could also use **with** statement. It extends the scope chain for a statement.

```js
var res = { name: "fsdfsd", details: "sdfsdf", password: "sdfsdgds" }

with(res){
  console.log(name)
  console.log(details)
  console.log(password)
}
```

> Using with is not recommended, and is forbidden in ECMAScript 5 strict mode. The recommended alternative is to assign the object whose properties you want to access to a temporary variable. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with)